# AngularJS: Let user identify corners of a rectangular object inside an image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would want to crop an rectangular photo shot from an oblique angle. I want to allow users to identify the corners of this photo by dragging around the corners of an initial rectangular crop window. Once the corners are identified, I can get send them to my OpenCV backend to transpose the image.

I've drawn a sample image for your idea. Do we have any AngularJS directives that I can use to get this done? Any sample implementations that I can use as a tutorial to achieve this?

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the coordinates of the image corners on a mouse click you can do something like this

```
$scope.addOnClick = function(event) {
        $scope.items.push( {
            "label": "Click",
            "value": 100,
            "x": event.offsetX-50,
            "y": event.offsetY-50,
        })
}
```

Once you get the coordinates then you can crop the image accordingly